# sending terminal/shell command from mysql to terminal and retrieve answer while looping cursor

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, command, shellexecute

I'm using php with MySQL on macOS. 
I would like to select a large amount of emails from a database and perform a dns lookup for each email in my selection using a dig command from the terminal/shell, something like: "dig gmail.com" . 
Of course, I can loop this select through php but it will be very slow compared to looping cursor on MySQL.
How to send terminal commands from mysql to the terminal and retrieve answer on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute shell commands from within an SQL query (thank god), or else it would be a horrible security vulnerability... You would have to do it from php.

P.S. It is however possible to execute shell commands from the MySQL command line utility

```
\! ls
```

...but if I understand your question, it won't help solve your current problem.

Comment: In mssql is possible to use shell command regularly and it is a great benefit for developers. If it is not possible to use shell commands in mysql this is disfunction, not a security benefit. it is worth as much as it payed...

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that you really mean ADDR_SPEC when you're talking about email addresses)

> but it will be very slow in compare with looping cursor on mysql

No not really. The only difference is that *depending on how you implement this* the PHP approach requires that you retrieve the entire result set before you start iterating through it. However breaking this up into smaller result sets is trivial.

Also, the limitation on the performance of your algorithm is the speed of DNS lookups - and that's all about latency - if your objective is to make this go faster then you should be running multple requests in parallel.

The next thing you should consider is that you've probably got multiple mailboxes for each MX, e.g. user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com.... While if you've got DNS caching setup properly there will be less overhead than going to the source each time, if you're working with a very large data set or will be doing this more than once, it makes a lot more sense to just work with unique MX host values, e.g.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(addr_spec FROM LOCATE('@', addr_spec)) AS mx2chk
 FROM yourtable
 WHERE addr_spec LIKE '%@%'
 AND (email_checked IS NULL
   OR email_checked<NOW() - INTERVAL 300 DAY )
 ;
```

Indeed, if your flagging the data then you can use your own database to verify the MX.

> using a dig command from terminal/shell

Please don't tell me that you're running a shell from a PHP controlling process to do a DNS lookup?

Comment: i'm trying not to using php at all but using macos system dig function

Comment: yes, I really mean ADDR_SPEC of course. I have distinctly prepared table with 1400 000 such entities, I just want to check them looping  cursor using only database